# Regex: Find only " that are not delimiters

Tags: regex, csv

I am trying to build a regex that finds all the `"` in a CSV file (seperated by `;`) that are not text delimiters. So the specifications are:

1. `"` is not at the beginning of a line
2. `"` is not preceeded by a `;`
3. `"` is not followed by a `;`
4. `"` is not at the end of a line

I use node.js so there is no look behind possible.

Here is an example line to test with:

`123123;"This is a text. These "quotes" should be matched, this one not";"text";4125;"Also no match"`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do simply:

```js
var s = '123123;"This is a text. These "quotes" should be matched, this one not";"text";4125;"Also no match"';
res = s.replace(/([^;])"([^;])/g, '$1$2');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Only thing that is missing is the 4th criteria, so I added a `\n` :

`([^;\n])"([^;\n])`

Comment: @boernard: You need to add `\n` only if there is a character after the last quote, like `blah blah"abc`

Comment: I tested this here https://regex101.com/r/jtDowM/1 and in the second row the last quote is being matched

Comment: @boernard:OK, But it's strange, I've tested whithin a perl script and it worked. Maybe some small differences in interpretation between languages.

Comment: @boernard: Would you like to remove as well double double quotes (ie. `""quotes""` or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
(?<!^|;)"(?!;|$)
```

- It uses a lookahead and lookbehind, which means, it won't work in JavaScript
- `(?<!^|;)` the preceding token cannot be `^` (start of string) and `;`
- `(?!;|$)` the subsequent token cannot be `$` (end of string) and `;`
- Use the global `/g` and the multiline flag `/m` to make it work

Here is a live example: https://regex101.com/r/bqdQCB/2

---

If you don't want to use the multi line flag `/m`, you can use the following regular expression (which also uses line breaks):

```
(?<!^|;|\r\n|\n)"(?!;|$|\r\n|\n)
```

- `\r\n` is a Windows line break and `\n` is a UNIX line break

Here is a live example: https://regex101.com/r/bqdQCB/3